# Deploying smart contracts from mobile device

Tags: solidity, android

I have recently started learning solidity but I don't have access to a laptop. All I have is a Samsung s4. I know it is not ideal, but is there a wallet that has the ability to deploy from Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyEtherWallet provides an offline signer for contract deployment [here](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts). You can use this to generate -and relay- your transaction.

### Edit:

For the current version (v3.8.1), you need to click "Deploy contract" first. In that page it asks for the bytecode (yes, you cannot directly paste Solidity code), however, obtaining the bytecode from the source code is trivial. You can use [Remix](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/) for that. Though I'm not sure if it will work with smartphones. If not, you need to find another Solidity compiler.

Comment: Can I paste the solidity code straight in there? It says json

Comment: @alXCrypto edited the answer.

Comment: @jeff Is it possible to use `MyEtherWallet` to invoke functions of my smart contract from my android phone and then get a transaction hash ? Thanks.